# Return String from Thread Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, return-value, delphi-xe6

I'm using Delphi XE6.

I have a thread where I pass a ID and would like to get back a string created by the thread. I looked at all examples, but they all getting values back when thread is running I just need it OnTerminate.

Calling the thread from a form:

```
StringReturnedFromThread := PrintThread.Create(MacId);

PrintThread = class(TThread)
  private        
    MyReturnStr, PrinterMacId : String;
  public
        constructor Create(MacId: String); reintroduce;
        procedure OnThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor PrintThread.Create(MacId: String);
begin
    inherited Create(False);
    OnTerminate := OnThreadTerminate;
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    PrinterMacId := MacId;
end;

procedure PrintThread.Execute;
begin
    PrepareConnection;
    MyReturnStr:= RequestPrintJobs(PrinterMacId);
end;

procedure PrintThread.OnThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin


end;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, then grab it from `OnTerminate` event handler. That one is called in the context of the main thread so it is safe for this purpose.

Comment: Do I have to change it to a function like this; OnThreadTerminate: String; Then Result := MyReturnStr;

Comment: No, you have it correct already (it must remain matching with the event prototype). Just process your strings inside that `OnThreadTerminate` handler somehow (I don't know what you want to do). Inside that method, it is safe to access main thread stuff.

Comment: I want it back to the form. Should I create a Read?

Comment: It's no good from code design, but you can even write that event handler to be part of that form. Or another bad practice can be accessing the predeclared global form variable from your current handler. Or pass and store the form reference to that thread and access it from thread field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to intercept thread termination. One way is to use TThread.OnTerminate event/callback.

Below a sample code.

Thread unit:

```
unit Processes;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TProcess = class(TThread)
  private
    FReturnStr: string;
    FMacId: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property MacId: string read FMacId write FMacId;
    property ReturnStr: string read FReturnStr write FReturnStr;
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

constructor TProcess.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TProcess.Execute;
begin
  // Some hard calculation here
  FReturnStr := FMacId + 'BLA';
end;

end.
```

Thread usage:

```
uses Processes;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var P: TProcess;
begin
  // Create the thread
  P := TProcess.Create;
  // Initialize it
  P.MacId := 'MID123';
  // Callback handler
  P.OnTerminate := OnProcessTerminate;
  // Let's go
  P.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnProcessTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var P: TProcess;
begin
  // The thread has been terminated
  P := TProcess(Sender);
  ShowMessage(P.ReturnStr);
end;
```

The thread will return `MID123BLA` on it's termination.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.